# Creating an Object and passing it to a vector at the same time ( in C++)

Tags: c++, object, vector

Can I pass an object to a vector and create it at the same time ? I will try to illustrate what I mean via an example.

```
#include <vector>

class testObject{
private:
   int someInt;
public:
   testObject(int a){ someInt=a; }
};

int main() {
   std::vector<testObject> testVector;
   testVector.push_back(testObject(2));
}
```

I have tried using something akin to the code above. Unsuprisingly no object was achtually added to the vector. As far as I understand `testObject(2)` does create an instance of `testObject` but it goes out of scope the moment the constructor is finished.

**UPDATE:**

Dear helpers/advisers. Thank you very much for you answers. I read through all the comments and the code examples and must now alter my question a bit. I added a member to the `testObject`-class. Now if I add an instance of the object to the vector (as shown in example above) the member seems to be empty. Now I think i would nee to allocate some memory to do that ? Usually I try to avoid allocation Memory via `new` for I am afraid of memory leaks and do not yet have the confidence in my programming skills. What would be the most sensible implementation ?

Comment: Your vector is of wrong type. It should be vector<testObject>.

Comment: Another problem may be the `testObject` doesn't store any data... Please post some code which you think fails and tell us what you expect and why.

Comment: what's object type? is it the same as testobject?

Comment: Even if class contains no data members, sizeof cannot be less than 1.

Comment: Can you add real code that compiles?

Comment: @billz thanks for the hint - it should have been vector<testObject> - i eddited that away

Answer (score 2):

It works with some minor fixes:

```
 class testObject{
 public:
       testObject(int){
       }
    };

int main()
{
  vector<testObject> testVector;
  testVector.push_back(testObject(2));
}
```

*This world has moved on, please upgrade your compiler to last version if you can. I haven't seen VC6.0 for over quite many years.*

Comment: I'm still using VC++ 6.0 for safety critical work!

Comment: my employer forces me to use one - I would gladly use a new compiler !!!

Comment: @PeterWood I don't understand your comment. Are you suggesting that VC++ 6.0 is somehow *safer* than modern compilers? Or are you complaining about your work?

Comment: @FredOverflow Well, the exclamation was in two ways, one that we're using such an old compiler, secondly that it is for safety critical reasons, which is dubious, and hopefully surprising to you. It's all to do with paper trails and proving you've taken adequate precautions, rather than safety in the intuitive meaning of the word. Sorry, I don't mean to be cynical, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

About the code, *billz*'s answer is correct.

To address your misgivings:

> Now if I add an instance of the object to the vector (as shown in
>   example above) the member seems to be empty.

It should work fine - please show how you're determining this.

> Now I think i would need
>   to allocate some memory to do that ?

The compiler *should* generate a default member-wise copy constructor for you. If your members are all value types (as here), this generally results in a correct shallow copy.

You can write it yourself explicitly, if you want somewhere to add logging or a breakpoint, but you shouldn't need to:

```
class testObject{
private:
   int someInt;
public:
   explicit testObject(int a) : someInt(a) {}
   // compiler should automatically handle copy like this:
   testObject(testObject const &other) : someInt(other.someInt) {}
   // and handle assignment like this:
   testObject& operator=(testObject const &other) {
      someInt = other.someInt;
      return *this;
   }
};
```

> Usually I try to avoid allocation
>   Memory via new for I am afraid of memory leaks and do not yet have the
>   confidence in my programming skills. What would be the most sensible
>   implementation ?

You don't need to worry about it for value types as above. If you need *reference* types, best practise is to wrap them in smart pointers or dedicated classes so you can *treat* them as value types (and save you having to write the copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor, by making the compiler-generated ones work correctly). I'm afraid I have no idea  how compatible this advice is with VC++ 6.0.

Comment: As far as I know smart pointers are only avliable via boost. I am also not familiar with dedicated classes - I will look into that. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<testObject> testVector;
testVector.push_back(testObject(2));
```

A faster alternative in C++11 is to let the vector create the testObject in place:

```
testVector.emplace_back(2);
```

This won't make any unnecessary copies or moves.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend that you adhere to some coding standard. Although not perfect, Google has decent [coding style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml) which you could adopt.

Whatever you're trying to do with your code, unless you're writing some kind of test for a class named Object, you could think about picking some other name for your class, e.g. TestClass. It's just a matter of intent: if you're testing OO capabilities of C++, then TestClass makes more sense than testObject.

Also, there's no code in your example that could verify that you actually appended an object to the vector. You could do it with something like this.

```
... some code here ...

int main()
{
    std::vector<testObject> testVector;
    std::cout << "Initial size: " << testVector.size() << std::endl;

    testVector.push_back(testObject(3));
    std::cout << "New size:     " << testVector.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I don't know if you know how to work with standard I/O streams, but you're not dealing with I/O in your example, so for the sake of completeness, add I/O to your example.

I intentionally omitted to apply any of stylistic advice I've given you in order to be consistent with previous examples, because consistency within some context is also important trait of a good programming style.

Finally, to answer your original question, if using `push_back`, C++ will **copy** your temporary object on the backside of your vector. (Already explained by @FredOverflow.) That basically means that vector handles memory management for you, so you don't have to worry about allocation or deallocation, but your only concern is where (i.e. at what index) you actually stored your object.

Comment: thank you very much for providing a link to a style guide - i read through one I found on the web and tried adhering to it as strictily as possible. Google's guide seems to be more comprehensive. I will endevour to incorporate that into my coding.